# Error: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo este método para eliminar dentro de mi clase StockMetodos

```
public static int Eliminar(int codDetalleCompra)
        {
            int retorno = 0;
            MySqlConnection conexion = ConexionBD.ObtenerConexion();

            MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("Delete from detalledecompra where CodigoDetalleCompra='{0}'", codDetalleCompra ), conexion);

            retorno = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conexion.Close();

            return retorno;

        }
```

y esto para que el botón eliminar ejecute:

```
private void btnEliminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Esta seguro de que desea eliminar la compra?", "Esta seguro?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                if (StockMetodos.Eliminar(compraStock.CodigoDetalleCompra) > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Compra eliminada correctamente", "Compra eliminada", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No se pudo eliminar la compra", "Compra no eliminada", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                }
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Se cancelo la eliminacion", "Eliminacion cancelada", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
```

a la hora de ejecutar me sale el error:

> "System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'
>
> StockBD.Form1.compraStock.get devolvió null."

¿Qué esta mal?

Comment: de donde sale `compraStock` ? o sea como lo instancias y asignas el valor de CodigoDetalleCompra

Comment: este codigo esta conectado a una base de datos en dbforge for my sql, el comprastock viene de esa clase  public DetalleDeCompra compraStock { get; set; }

Comment: pero si te retorna null quiere decir que en la db ese campo puede no tener ningun dato, quizas debas agregar la validacion

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

En el método Eliminar la linea de

```
MySqlConnection conexion = ConexionBD.ObtenerConexion();
```

`ConexionDB.ObtenerConexion();` ¿es estática?
de lo contrario deberias poner

```
MySqlConnection conexion = new ConexionBD.ObtenerConexion();
```

Estaría bueno que hagas lo siguiente:

Proba hacer lo siguiente en la clase:

```
    public static int Eliminar(int codDetalleCompra)
    {
        int retorno = 0;
        try
        {

            MySqlConnection conexion = ConexionBD.ObtenerConexion();

            MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("Delete from detalledecompra where CodigoDetalleCompra='{0}'", codDetalleCompra), conexion);

            retorno = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conexion.Close();

            return retorno;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           //Debugguear el ex y mirar el obj StackTrace copiar y pegar el codigo debajo para saber donde es el error
        }


    }
        retorno = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conexion.Close();
}catch(Exception ex)
{
//aca debuggea Ex y mira el obj de StackTrace y por favor copia el mensaje de error.
}



        return retorno;

    }
```

Comment: cual es la solucion que le propones? basicamente le indicas que uses el try..catch para caprutar un error que ya conoce porque lo menciona en la pregunta

Comment: trae mas errores :/

Comment: El metodo ObtenerConexion eue devuelve ademas es estático ?.
no funcina por que quedo dos veces el catch igual me gustaria saber que dice la variable ex en el objeto Stacktrace